# How to run a GWAS in command line with Plink2?

Tags: genetics, gwas

I am trying to run a GWAS in the command line with plink version 2, however when I run the following command  `plink2 --file hapmap1` I get the following error `Error: Unrecognized flag ('--file')`

I am trying to follow this tutorial https://zzz.bwh.harvard.edu/plink/tutorial.shtml#t6

Do I need to replace the file name in the command? (I have tried that but still get the same error)

I am unsure what to do as this is the first time I am using plink. I read somewhere that this command isnt compatible with plink2 but that was in 2017, so I am not sure how relevant that is now.

Comment: try `plink2 --bfile hapmap1`. If this does not work then use `PLINK 1.9`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation you linked, the flag you need is `--bflag`: note the 'b'.

Comment: So I have done that, do I need to replace the ```hapmap1``` with the file name? As I still seem to be running into errors. Wait I see it says it should exist but I just have an ordinary hapmap file

Comment: I can't say I'm familiar with plink, but it looks like you download the sample data as a zip, and then unzip that download into a directory. You execute `plink` from within the directory which you unzipped the download. If you run `ls -l` you should see entries such as `hapmap1.bim`, `hapmap1.fed`, etc. `plink` is looking for the prefix, in this case `hapmap1`. If your files are called something different use the appropriate prefix in place of `hapmap1`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `--file` flag supported in plink2.

Depending on the format version of your genetic data, you would need to specify one of the following:

- if you have plink1.9 format files (`hapmap1.{bed,bim,fam}`), then you should use `plink2 --bfile hapmap`;
- if you have plink2 format files (`hapmap1.{pgen,psam,pvar}`), then you should use `plink2 --pfile hapmap`; or
- if your `pvar` file is compressed with Z standard (`hapmap1.{pgan,psam,pvar.zst}`), then you should use `plink2 --pfile hapmap vzs`.

The official documentation for plink2 is here: https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/2.0/input